How to add buoyancy to objects in unity
I have a problem at unity urp shadergraphs. I made a shadergraph that allows to make waves with dynamically. But as you know this shader just works on GPU. I tried write code which makes a waves with c# to affect on mesh with vertex.
But my code doesn't give same waves with shadergraph wavemaker. So, the waves that I create with C# code are not same waves with shader waves. What is my options to float objects on water surface? Or is there any logically way to transform this shader to CPU?
What is my options to float objects on water surface ? Or is there any logically way to transform this shader to CPU ?
Here is my wavemaker shader:
shadergraph unity buoyancy

There is nothing inherently problematic with running a shader on a CPU, but you need to ensure that things like random values are generated the exact same way. It might also be possible to run any buoyancy calculations on the GPU, or to read data from the GPU to the CPU or vice versa. But I'm no GPU programmer, and I'm not sure how much access to the GPU unity will give you.

I would try the AsyncGPUReadback. It has few frames of delay, but that should be okay for buoyancy.
